# Question about arithmetic progression. stuck on one of the answers

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

So i was doing this question on my workbook. I did the first question and i was correct. but on the second question, same logic, same solving way, but i was wrong.
here is question 1, finding a closed form for
$$a_1=3\qquad a_{n+1}=a_n+2,n\ge2$$
Thus I have
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+2,d=2$$ 
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2$$
$$a_n=a_1+(n-1)*2$$
$$a_n=a_1+2n-2$$
$$a_1=3$$
$$a_n=3+2n-2$$
$$a_n=2n+1,n\ge1$$
the last line was the answer, and i did it right.but the same logic couldn't be applied here
$$a_1=1$$
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2n-1,n\ge2$$
heres my solution 
$$d=2n-1$$
$$a_n=a_1+(n-1)*(2n-1)$$
$$a_n=a_1+2n^2-3n+1$$
$$a_1=1$$
$$a_n=2n^2-3n+2$$
Then i couldn't simplify it futher. But the answer says else-wise
$$a_n=n^2$$

Comment: The second example is not an arithmetic progression, hence you can not just use the formulas attached to arithmetic progressions.

Comment: The second case isn't an arithmetic progression, so the step $a_n=a_1+(n-1)*(2n-1)$ is incorrect.

Comment: +1 Welcome to MSE.  My compliments on a well-formulated question.  You stated the problem clearly and completely, and showed all your work.  Keep it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Remember that an arithmetic progression is a series where two **consecutive** terms have the same common difference.

Also, note that $a_n,a_{n+1}$ are two consecutive terms and $a_{n-1},a_n$ are two consecutive terms.

So, by definition, $a_n-a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n+1}-a_n$ should be constant common difference.

However, for the second question, the common difference is dependent on $n$ and thus not constant. So the second one is not an AP.

Hoewvwer an alternate approach to solve the second problem exists.

Using the fact $a_n-a_{n-1}=2n-1$ we get,

$$a_2-a_1=3$$
$$a_3-a_2=5$$
$$a_4-a_3=7$$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$a_n-a_{n-1}=2n-1$$

Adding the two columns we have 
$$a_n-a_1=3+5+7+...+(2n-1)$$
$$\implies a_n=1+3+5+7+...+(2n-1)\text{ [since a_1=1]}$$

So now the right side is an AP.

Add it and voila!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to note, that that because n is variable, differences are in arithmetic progression in this case.
This means, we can sum up all the differences as in an arithmetic progression.  $n-1$ terms gives us ${(n-1)(3+(2n-1))\over 2}$ we can then add this to $a_1$ getting $1+(n-1)(n+1)= 1+n^2-1=n^2$

Answer (score 1):

You can't treat the second recurrence as an arithmetic progression since its step size isn't constant.

That $a_n=n^2$ there may perhaps be most easily seen visually:

```
...o... a_1
..oox.. a_2
.oooxx. a_3
ooooxxx a_4
```

and then you fold the triangle of `x` onto that of `o`, obtaining a square of size $n$. The formal proof may be achieved via induction.

Comment: Mind if i ask what the circles and the crosses are meant to be? I really have no clue

Comment: @doodlerdoodle They are just meant to show you that you can flip the x's and place them onto the o's so as to form a square.